# Is there any generalization of Frobenius group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ act on $\Omega$ transitively and $\chi(g)$ is equal to number of the elements fixed by $g$.

If $\chi(g)\leq 1$ for all $g\in G\setminus\{e\}$ then $G$ is a Frobenius group. There are many theorems related to these groups. For example,

$N=\{g\in G | \chi(g)=0 \}\cup \{e\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G=N\rtimes Stab(\omega)$ for $\omega\in \Omega$. Moreover, $N$ must be a nilpotent group.

If we set $\chi(g)\leq k$ for a small integer $k$, Can we get similar results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but there is a classification of (finite) [Zassenhaus groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_group), which are doubly transitive groups in which no non-identity element fixes more than $2$ points. So the point stabilizer is a Frobenius group. The proof of the classification is long and difficult, but it pre-dates the classification of finite simple groups.

Examples include the groups ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, ${\rm PGL(2,q)}$ and the Suzuki groups, and some solvable examples.